# Javascript JQuery Get Number and display icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm very new to javascript so please bare with.  I'm trying to get the number of "unread notifications" from a file then if the number if above 0 I want it to display an image inside of a div.  If not then I want it to remain blank.

Here is what I have so far and right now it's displaying in the div the number of notifications.  I don't want it to do that.  I just want it to display an icon if there is more than 0 unread notifications.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");

   var value = $("#notes_number").load("getnumber.php");

   if(value > 0){
    //display icon...not sure the javascript code for this.

    }

});
```

Comment: You might want to [RTFM](http://api.jquery.com/load/)...

Comment: not sure I understand how RTFM will help.  Can you elaborate

Answer (score 0):

`load()` doesn't return a value, it loads the response into the DOM element, you want to use `$.get()` instead:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.get('getnumber.php',function(data){
        if(parseInt(data,10) > 0){
            //show icon
            $("#notes_number").html('icon here');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can display an icon in any number of ways. It all depends on your HTML structure.

Assuming you have a header bar and a div with class `.messages` you could update it like this:

```
$("#header .messages").text(value + " new messages waiting.").addClass("new");
```

This would update the text in your messages box and give it a `new` class which could have an style associated with it to display an icon as a background-image, like this:

```
.messages.new {
    background-image: url(images/new_icon.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: left center;
}
```

You will first need to correct your incorrect use of `load()`, however. I would suggest using `get()` with a callback function on complete, assuming that `getnumber.php' just returns a string.